# Setting a UILabel inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So the thing is I have 4 UICollectionViewCells inside CollectionView that is inside a TableView. (I set the TableViewController as the DataSource and Delegate of the CollectionView).

Now, I've stored a string array of 4 elements inside a CKRecord. How can I set the label inside the 4 cells, so that they display each string of the array?

Here's what it looks like:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 4
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CvCell

        let poll = polls[indexPath.row] // polls is a [CKRecord]()
        let labelContent = poll["4strings"] as? [String]


        cell.cellLabel.titleLabel?.text = labelContent

        return cell

    }
```

Now obviously, that's not going to work since I basically set the label of each cell to the array itself. How can I write a for loop that goes through each CvCell label, or rather how can I specify the label of e.g. the third cell to set it to the value of labelContent[2]?

UPDATE:

Totally forgot to mention, the data structure in the cloud basically looks like this:

```
array1 = [1a, 1b, 1c, 1d]

array2 = [2a, 3b, 2c, 2d]

array3 = [3a, 2b, 3c, 3d]

array4 = [4a, 4b, 4c, 4d]
```

And if I try to do what @user3353890 proposed, it's giving me the following results for my tableview:

```
tableview1cell - collectionview1 : [1a, 2b, 3c, 4d] -> these are the collectionviewcell labels

tableview2cell - collectionview2 : [1a, 2b, 3c, 4d]

tableview3cell - collectionview3 : [1a, 2b, 3c, 4d]

tableview4cell - collectionview4 : [1a, 2b, 3c, 4d]
```

However what I want is:

```
tableview1cell - collectionview1 : [1a, 1b, 1c, 1d]

tableview2cell - collectionview2 : [2a, 2b, 2c, 2d]

tableview3cell - collectionview3 : [3a, 3b, 3c, 3d]

tableview4cell - collectionview4 : [4a, 4b, 4c, 4d]
```

I'm sorry I have a really hard time explaining this, but I hope someone gets what I'm trying to do?

Comment: is labelContent supposed to be an array of strings? You can't set label.text to an array. If you want to display ever string in the array on one label, use a for loop to iterate through the array and add each string to the previous one in order to create on string to display in the label.

Comment: Yes I know that this obv. doesn't work, as I described in the last paragraph, I want to set the first string of the array to the label of the first collectionview cell, the second string of the array to the label of the second collectionview cell, and so on..

Comment: However, I am not sure how to use a for loop here since I only return one cell?

Comment: My apologies, I think I understand what you want to do now. I'm going to post an answer below and we can work off of that.

Comment: Nesting a collectionView inside a tableView is a bad practice, as this adds extra overhead for dequeing cells, and makes your code more complex than it should be. You can achieve the same result by just using a collectionView.

Comment: So it would be better to nest a collectionView inside a collectionView? How would that help making the code less complex?

Comment: I actually agree with @SanderSaelmans on this. My apologies for not suggesting this sooner, but I got so caught up in trying to understand what you were trying to achieve and then trying to find a solution that I didn't think of suggesting an alternative. I'll add another answer below that would probably work better for you by just using collectionView.

Comment: Not a problem! As I'm still a novice anyway, it doesn't hurt to get some insights at different coding practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not returning one cell. You're going to ultimately return 4 cells because you stipulated that you want 4 items in each section in the numberOfItemsInSection method.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}
```

cellForItemAtIndexPath coordinates how you want to display each cell. Because you stated that there are 4 items in a section, this method will get called 4 times, returning 1 cell each time it is called to be an item in that section.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CvCell

    let poll = polls[collectionView.tag] // polls is a [CKRecord]()
    let labelContent = poll["4strings"] as? [String]

    // This should give you the string that you want.
    let myString = labelContent[indexPath.row]

    // Display the string in the label.
    cell.cellLabel.titleLabel?.text = myString

    return cell

}
```

After you set the labelContent array, get  myString at each index by passing indexPath.row into the array. So for the 1st cell (0 index) it gives you the 1st string in your array (0 index).

**Edit**

when you create poll, use indexPath.section in order to keep the correct order of all your arrays while displaying data.

```
let poll = polls[collectionView.tag]
```

**Edit 2**

In your tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath Method, when you create a cell, set the cell's collectionView.tag to indexPath.section

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.collectionView.delegate = self
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section
    return cell
}
```

Then when you dequeue your collectionView, you can access the proper array by calling collectionView.tag -as seen above- in order to get the indexPath of the tableViewCell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I'm sorry I kinda meant I only return 1 "blueprints" of a cell 4 times. Also, I totally forgot to mention that I got 4 CKRecords (hence I declare poll to polls[indexpath.row])and each of these 4 CKRecords have 1 array of 4 strings.
I'll update my post to give you a better insight

Comment: No worries, thanks for the additional information! Give me a few moments and I'll try to come up with a solution

Comment: @user3545063 I've updated the solution above. I believe this should work now.

Comment: Oh, right! It almost works as expected now, however it only displays 1 array in the correct order for all of the 4 uitableviewcells (instead of array 1 - uitableviewcell 1, array 2- uitableviewcell 2, etc..)

Comment: ok, I know why. It's because we're using the section of the CollectionView, which will always be 0, instead of the section of the TableView. So we need to get the current section of the TableView

Comment: you're welcome! did you figure out how to get the tableview section? I can work on that if you still need assistance

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure it out, if you don't mind any help is definitely welcome!

Comment: yeah i'll play around with it and get back to you. I have a few ideas i'll test out

Comment: So my solution was just to create a global variable and whenever a tableview cell gets created, i set it to the indexPath.row (of the tableview)

In case you have a better solution feel free to share!

Comment: Hey, sorry, I had a few other things to take care of. I have a better solution for you! I would try to steer clear of global variables, it's not generally viewed as good programming practice. I'll update my solution with a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Worked flawlessly. 

I have another problem to take care of now: Although the labels seem to be properly "connected" to the cloud, the Label sometimes doesn't update and just displays the default text (It only happens to cell that aren't on screen when loaded)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Happy to help, although as @sander saelmans mentioned, it is a slightly complex solution. Check the other answer a listed for an easier to maintain alternative that should accomplish what you want. Either way, you have two solutions that work now.

Comment: I don't have much experience using cloudkit, but I'm sure there are ample resources online that teach you how to use it properly. My best guess would be to start by looking into GCD and how you're handling downloading the information. I could be wrong, but hopefully it's somewhere to start. Knowing GCD will be valuable regardless. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

A better solution so you don't have to nest a collectionView within a tableView:

This gives you the number of sections you want. One section for each array in your "polls" array:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return polls.count
}
```

This will take the sub-array for each corresponding section and allow the number of items in that collectionView section to correspond with the number of items in the array:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let poll = polls[section] as? [String]
    return poll.count
}
```

Display your collectionView cells here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CvCell

    let poll = polls[indexPath.section] // polls is a [CKRecord]()
    let labelContent = poll["4strings"] as? [String]

    // This should give you the string that you want.
    let myString = labelContent[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellLabel.titleLabel?.text = myString

    return cell

}
```

Comment: I'll look into this tomorrow, thanks! 

How would this affect my Storyboard layout though? Do I just have to remove the tableview and replace it with a collection view?

Comment: yes, just use a collectionview or collectionview controller. Don't forget to attach your delegate and datasource if you use the former. Your storyboard will be much more simple. You won't be trying to nest collectionviews within tableviewcells. It's also much easier to maintain and scale if you keep it simple.